# could anyone tell me how to draw this triangle and lots of arrow

Tags: tikz-arrows

[image]

```
\center
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[anchor=north]{$2$}
  -- (5,0) node[anchor=north]{$3$}
  -- (2.5,5) node[anchor=south]{$1$}
  -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Could anyone help me to complete the picture thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't hard to construct something like this, but I feel that you would benefit more from more abstract questions, which ultimately will allow you to do all these things on your own. All you need are a few polar coordinates, and some edges.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill},
    >={Latex[length=6pt,round]},scale=pi,
    shift right/.style={to path={
    ($(\tikztostart)!#1!270:(\tikztotarget)$)
    --($(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztostart)$) }}]
 \draw (90:1) coordinate[dot,label=90:{$\mathsf{1}$},label=45:{$\mathsf{Z_0}$}] (1)
  -- coordinate[pos=0.5,dot,label={[anchor=190]10:{$\mathsf{Z_1}$}}] (Z1) (210:1) coordinate[label=210:{$\mathsf{2}$}] (2)
  -- coordinate[pos=0.4,yshift=1ex,dot,label=90:{$\mathsf{Z_4}$}] (Z4) (-30:1) coordinate[label=-30:{$\mathsf{3}$}] (3) -- cycle;
 \path[every coordinate node/.append style={dot}] 
 (Z1) ++ (-30:0.6) coordinate[label=45:{$\mathsf{Z_2}$}] (Z2) 
    ++ (-30:0.3) coordinate[label=45:{$\mathsf{Z_3}$}] (Z3); 
 \path[->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] (1) edge[shift right=2pt] (Z1)
  foreach \X in {1,2,3} {(Z\X) edge (Z\the\numexpr\X+1)}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much but I am using \documentclass[8pt]{article}

Comment: @riemann I certainly do not prevent you from using `\documentclass[8pt]{article}` but your question does not mention this. You can just add `\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc} ` to the preamble and place the `tikzpicture` wherever you need it.